# MS SQL Linked Server Abstraction - refactor queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, linked-server

I have a SQL Server Instance which has a remote Linked Server (192.168.0.2) set up. In my database I have found that there are 50 local database objects (views, functions & stored procedures) querying tables within another database on the remote linked server.

My 2 different environments queries as follows:

LIVE:
`select * from [192.168.0.2].DB1.dbo.MyTable`

PRE-PROD:
`select * from [192.168.0.2].DB2.dbo.MyTable`

There is a potential risk involved when I duplicate my database to create/refresh my pre-prod environment. The risk is that on the prod environment, my database will query the remote database called DB1; on the pre-prod environment, my database will query the remote database called DB2. So for my pre-prod environment to safely use the test remote database instead of the live remote database, I am forced to have to remember to update all 50 local database objects to use DB2 instead of DB1.

I have re-factored it a bit by altering the 50 local objects to rather query views, which then queries the linked server's appropriate database.

Now I am able to query as follows within my 50 local objects:

LIVE:
`select * from uvw_MyTable`

PRE-PROD:
`select * from uvw_MyTable`

I still sit with 5 different views that I will need to manually update with every pre-prod refresh, to explicitly query DB2 instead of DB1 on the Linked Server. Is it at all possible to re-factor this scenario even more or even to make it more dynamic and get rid of the hard-coding of the different database names all together, if so kindly assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another level of abstraction.

Create local synonyms for the tables on the linked server.

```
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[MyTableSynonym] FOR [192.168.0.2].DB1.dbo.MyTable
```

Rewrite the queries:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MyTableSynonym]
```

Create script to recreate synonyms (DROP & CREATE) to point to test database objects when refreshing the pre-production environment.

Comment: Hi Dean, thank you for the feedback provided. This is a great idea, I would still however have to amend (hard-code) these 5 synonyms (one for each table being referenced on remote DB) to explicitly point to the correct remote databases. If possible at all, I would like to make it fully dynamic. This does however make the maintenance less tedious.

Comment: You do have a script to restore the database, right? Just add a few lines of code to this script and youre done with it for good.